# ksql statement for extracting comma delimited message to it is own fields

Tags: ksqldb

I have a JSON object that has fewer fields.

```
{
"@timestamp": "2019-01-14T14:34:47.617Z",
"message": "20190114T063447-0800,dm-2,SSD2T-backarea,1.99,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00",
"node": "hostnameA",
}
```

what would be the proper way to disect `message` field to it is own fields as well as keep `node` and `@timestamp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. You'd be looking for some kind of `SPLIT` function, which doesn't currently exist. I've logged this as a suggested enhancement [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/2349).

Where is your data coming from? Do you have the option of getting the `message` field as structured JSON instead? Or the entire payload as comma-delimited?

Comment: It is coming from beats Elasticsearch products.  Basically, I run utility which dump as comma delimited to the file and `Filbeat` pushes it further to `Kafka`. We use `Logstash` for `ETL` before it lands on `Elastic`.  Also, I currently evaluate `Druid` for this kind of load.  Payload looks like this https://jqplay.org/s/bpkTob_TA9 .  I was playing with `ksql` and thought to `Dockarise` server and change deployment strategy.

Comment: if you have a utility dumping to CSV, you could dump to Kafka instead directly into Kafka using `kafkacat` etc. Or, keep the CSV but use Kafka Connect  with https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir (see https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksql-in-action-enriching-csv-events-with-data-from-rdbms-into-AWS/),

Comment: I have pretty huge env.  Beats seem better suited for that since also provide monitoring aspect from agents to `Marvel`.  I can easily spot it if there are any issues in env.

Comment: That's fair enough. I guess I would just try to avoid flat files in the process where possible, and push to Kafka directly (whether with beats, logstash, Kafka Connect…whatever).